# Is it possible to have event-based communication between browser windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Is it possible to have *event-based* communication between browser tabs/windows?

I known that it could be (at least theoretically) possible using *local storage*. Could you please provide small example of code doing that? Just send event in one tab, and receive it in another.

Are there any libraries/jquery-plugins that do that?

(I know that I can communicate between windows/tabs of the same browser using cookies; but that is not what I need; I would prefer event-based approach, I don't want recheck the state of the cookies every millisecond).

Comment: Take a look at [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I don't think that would work for tabs since you need a reference to the window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage#Syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Localstorage has events that you can subscribe to  to syncronize other pages.

Note: If you update a key's value in window A, the event will *not* be triggered in window A. It will be triggered in windows B & C.

Here is a demo:
http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Open this page in several tabs. change the value on the input and see it reflected in divs.

Here is the code The Javascript:

```
var dataInput = document.getElementById('data'),
output = document.getElementById('fromEvent');

// handle updates to the storage-event-test  key in other windows
addEvent(window, 'storage', function (event) {
  if (event.key == 'storage-event-test') {
    output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
  }
});

// Update the storage-event-test key when the value on the input is changed
addEvent(dataInput, 'keyup', function () {
  localStorage.setItem('storage-event-test', this.value);
});
```

Markup:

```
<div>
      <p>Your test data: <input type="text" name="data" value="" placeholder="change me" id="data" /> <small>(this is only echoed on <em>other</em> windows)</small></p>
      <p id="fromEvent">Waiting for data via <code>storage</code> event...</p>
</div>
```

The HTML 5 spec discusses all the information passed in the event:

```
[Constructor(DOMString type, optional StorageEventInit eventInitDict)]
interface StorageEvent : Event {
  readonly attribute DOMString key;
  readonly attribute DOMString? oldValue;
  readonly attribute DOMString? newValue;
  readonly attribute DOMString url;
  readonly attribute Storage? storageArea;
};

dictionary StorageEventInit : EventInit {
  DOMString key;
  DOMString? oldValue;
  DOMString? newValue;
  DOMString url;
  Storage? storageArea;
};
```

From:  http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event

Using this event, you can make other pages react to when a specific key in local storage is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Give [SignalRamp](https://github.com/TimHeckel/SignalRamp) a chance.

You can attach any of the bindable class names to elements to syncronize the corresponding mousedown, mouseup, hover (mouseover, mouseout) or click events in the UI.