# Using 'window.open' after 'window.close' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a page that requests a password from user, and if the condition statement is satisfied, 
I want the current page to be closed, and a new window be opened instead of the former page.

I had no problem with my code in my PC's localhost and it was working without any problem. But when I upload the page into my server, there is a bad problem.

It closes the current page as I want, but it doesn't open the new window.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$var1="701016";
$pass=$_POST['password'];
if ($pass==$var1) 
 { ?>
<script>
window.close();
window.open("hb.html","","height=800, width=1000, left=150");

</script>
<?php
ob_start();
}
elseif ($pass=="")
{header("location:empty.html");}

else {header("location:error.html");}

?>
```

Problem is with lines 7, 8

For opening window new I tried this too, but it was not effective.

```
window.close();
myWindow = window.open("hb.html","mywindow","height=800, width=1000,left=150");
```

I've got so confused.
Thank you.

Comment: did you try to simply turn opening and closing arround ? 
window.open("hb.html","","height=800, width=1000, left=150");window.close();

Comment: yes , it's not working too :(

Comment: It's because your new page is blocked by pop-up blocker and when you close current page you loose reference to blocked page.

Comment: thanks Givi.
what do you offer me to do ?

Comment: Look at [Is it possible to have event-based communication between browser windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735706/is-it-possible-to-have-event-based-communication-between-browser-windows/14792159#14792159) and [window.open MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around.

```
window.open("hb.html","","height=800, width=1000, left=150");  
window.close();
```